# "Object reference not set" error in PageTitle.ascx.cs page

Tags: acumatica

How can I resolve this error? I am facing this error only in my local instance, not in staging.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Could you please provide some more info? Is this error appearing for every screen or for some particular screen? could you provide an aspx code of the screen? Have you changed web.config?